# Storing webforms data within PHP pages

Tags: php, webforms, storage

I was reading a book about PHP and I wanted to know how can you store data(of web forms) in PHP pages? I know the process of creating a php file and recieving the data using $_POST(or any other way like this). But those values would be overwritten when you submit the webform again.

Without using the database or emailing the data, is there a way to store multiple webform's data in PHP?

Comment: In any case you will create some kind of database to store the values. It's your decision if those are just files or a database like MySQL. Apart from that you question is very broad so it's not clear what you're specifically concerned about, so those who answer can only guess. You might want to add more information to your question, e.g. what should happen with the data after it has been stored.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to store submissions from multiple sessions (or clients), you'd have to use some sort of database.
It could be an RDBMS like MySQL, and it could be a simple file: http://www.dummies.com/how-to/content/storing-data-with-php-flat-file-or-database.html

Comment: Can you please elaborate how can I do with with just a simple file? Do you mean file writing?

Comment: Yes. Here is a simple tutorial for this approach: http://www.albinoblacksheep.com/tutorial/flat

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is using a database, since MySQL is working very well together with php, often a php server includes MySQL and phpmyadmin which makes it easier to create and edit the database, then you just need a php script you include at the top op your page to set up the MySQL connection.

If this didn't convince you to use a database you could use this code as well:

```
$filename = "<your filename here>";
$content = "username=".$_POST['username'].":password=".$_POST['password']."{etc etc etc}."\n";

file_put_contents($filename,$content,FILE_APPEND);
```

The code above adds a row with the content to your file with the delimiter `:` (colon).

Make sure the filename already exitst somthing like: data.txt

Comment: And then you can open the file by using file_get_contents, exploding first on the \n to get row by row array and then explode using the delimiter collon, and then you can explode it using =
your array would look like this:
$username1 = explodedArray[0][0][1];
$password1 = explodedArray[0][1][1];